# How do I define a `ref` for dynamically created Comboboxes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am an old programmer but new to javascript. I am working on a small E-Commerce app. My products or items have up to twenty custom user defined properties. For instance, the category "screws" had two custom properties "Length" and "Thread".

I dynamically create a Combobox filter for each active custom property. I have added a button that I need to reset all dynamically created Combobox filters back to "Any" when clicked.

If my Comboboxes were statically defined, this is the basic idea I am trying to implement:

```
import React from 'react';
import Combobox from "react-widgets/Combobox";

class Sample extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.combo1 = React.createRef();
        this.combo2 = React.createRef();
    }    

    render() {
        let buttonClick = () => {
            this.combo1.current.value = "Any";
            this.combo2.current.value = "Any";
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={() => buttonClick() }>Reset Filters</button>
                <Combobox data={["Any", "1 1/2", "1 1/4"]} ref={this.combo1} />
                <Combobox data={["Any", "Red", "Green", "Blue"]} ref={this.combo2} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Sample;
```

How do I define a `ref` for dynamically created Comboboxes?

Relevant section from my component:

```
...
<p style={{ marginBottom: 0 }}>Filters:</p>                   
<button>Reset Filters</button>                            
{this.state.filters !== [] ? this.state.filters.map(filter => 
    <div>
        <p style={{ marginBottom: 0 }}>{filter.name}</p>
        <Combobox defaultValue="Any" data={filter.values} onChange={(e) => filterChanged(e, filter.property) } />
    </div>) : null}
...
```

I am sure I made quite a few errors. I welcome any constructive criticism.

Comment: It looks like you could cut down the content of your code by a lot. You should always remove noise from your example. Never copy paste your existing code. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @JuanMendes thank you for your comment. I welcome any constructive criticism.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you really need refs to achieve your goal? From what I understand you want to have a button that reset some Comboboxes selected values and I believe this would best be achieved by some state management using the `value` property of react-widgets' `Combobox` than with refs.

I've created [a small sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-feather-tteo3y?file=/src/App.js) that tries to reproduce approximately your needs and do some state management to show you how this can be achieved. That being said it does not use class-based components because I'm more used to function-based ones + hooks but you should be able to achieve it similarly via `this.setState()` + `this.state` in your class-based component instead of the `useState` hook in the sandbox.

Comment: Your sandbox code got me pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.combo1 = null;
    this.combo2 = null;

    this.setCombo1Ref = element => {
      this.combo1 = element;
    };

    this.setCombo2Ref = element => {
      this.combo2 = element;
    };
  }

  buttonClick = () => {
    this.combo1.querySelector("input").value = "Any";
    this.combo2.querySelector("input").value = "Any";
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <>
      <button onClick={this.buttonClick }>Reset Filters</button>
      <div>
        <div ref={this.setCombo1Ref}>
        <Combobox data={["Any", "1 1/2", "1 1/4"]} />
        </div>
        <div ref={this.setCombo2Ref}>
        <Combobox data={["Any", "Red", "Green", "Blue"]} />
        </div>
      </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

May be this can help please check. Used callback ref and wrapped the element with div.